# Python won't print my .csv file content correctly

Tags: python, csv

Basically, I am writing a program that writes into a .csv file and can print the information out, however, when I try to print the contents of it on the program it gives me \r\n at the end of each row.

Example: Name,Info1,Info2\r\n

I need to have it print without the \r\n part.

This is the code I am currently using to do this:

```
if menu == '4':
    f = open('MFP.csv', 'rb')
    for row in f:
        print(row)
```

ps: The if statement part is there because I have multiple options, all of which work fine except this one.

Comment: Did you try writing your file without the 'b' mode?

Comment: @GeorgeD wow it worked, thank you. I really appreciate it.